# Eliminate for loops in numpy implementation

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have the following dataset in numpy

```
indices | real data (X)    |targets (y)
        |                  |
0   0   | 43.25 665.32 ... |2.4      } 1st block
0   0   | 11.234           |-4.5     }
0   1     ...               ...      } 2nd block
0   1                                } 
0   2                                } 3rd block
0   2                                }
1   0                                } 4th block
1   0                                }
1   0                                }
1   1                       ...
1   1                       
1   2
1   2
2   0
2   0 
2   1
2   1
2   1
...
```

Theses are my variables

```
idx1 = data[:,0]
idx2 = data[:,1]
X = data[:,2:-1]
y = data[:,-1]
```

I also have a variable `W` which is a 3D array.

What I need to do in the code is loop through all the blocks in the dataset and return a scalar number for each block after some computation, then sum up all the scalars, and store it in a variable called `cost`. Problem is that the looping implementation is very slow, so I'm trying to do it vectorized if possible. This is my current code. Is it possible to do this without for loops in numpy?

```
IDX1 = 0
IDX2 = 1

# get unique indices
idx1s = np.arange(len(np.unique(data[:,IDX1])))
idx2s = np.arange(len(np.unique(data[:,IDX2])))

# initialize global sum variable to 0
cost = 0
for i1 in idx1s:
    for i2 in idx2:

        # for each block in the dataset
        mask = np.nonzero((data[:,IDX1] == i1) & (data[:,IDX2] == i2))

        # get variables for that block
        curr_X = X[mask,:]
        curr_y = y[mask]
        curr_W = W[:,i2,i1]

        # calculate a scalar  
        pred = np.dot(curr_X,curr_W)
        sigm = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-pred))
        loss = np.sum((sigm- (0.5)) * curr_y)

        # add result to global cost
        cost += loss
```

Here is some sample data

```
data = np.array([[0,0,5,5,7],
                 [0,0,5,5,7],
                 [0,1,5,5,7],
                 [0,1,5,5,7],
                 [1,0,5,5,7],
                 [1,1,5,5,7]])
W = np.zeros((2,2,2))
idx1 = data[:,0]
idx2 = data[:,1]
X = data[:,2:-1]
y = data[:,-1]
```

Comment: why don't you simply use `idx1s=np.unique(data[:,IDX1])`? If there are no holes in the indeces you get the same results. If there are holes idx1s.max()<np.unique(data[:,IDX1]).max().

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano yes, I could use that, it's just np.unique doesn't always preserve order but I guess that doesn't matter in this case

Comment: you can sort it, then. it's one operation less

Comment: @siamii From the docs of np.unique:
"Returns the sorted unique elements of an array"

Answer (score 3):

That `W` was tricky... Actually, your blocks are pretty irrelevant, apart from getting the right slice of `W` to do the `np.dot` with the corresponding `X`, so I went the easy route of creating an `aligned_W` array as follows:

```
aligned_W = W[:, idx2, idx1]
```

This is an array of shape `(2, rows)` where `rows` is the number of rows of your data set. You can now proceed to do your whole calculation without any for loops as:

```
from numpy.core.umath_tests import inner1d
pred = inner1d(X, aligned_W.T)
sigm = 1.0 / (1.0 + np.exp(-pred))
loss = (sigm - 0.5) * curr_y
cost = np.sum(loss)
```

Comment: This is amazing. Just a curiosity: would this work also if some index is missing?

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't. The `aligned_W` array is a (probably repeating) copy of the data of `W` for the corresponding indices, but there is no constraint for all of the data having to be fetched by the fancy indexing that I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Then The only possible problem with this is that `aligned_W` can become a memory eater if `idxn` and/or the first dimension of `W` are very large. (this is not a criticism)

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the major reason your code is slow is the following line:

```
mask = np.nonzero((data[:,IDX1] == i1) & (data[:,IDX2] == i2))
```

Because you repeatedly scan your input arrays for small number of  rows of interest. So you need to do the following:

```
ni1 = len(np.unique(data[:,IDX1]))
ni2 = len(np.unique(data[:,IDX2]))
idx1s = np.arange(ni1)                         
idx2s = np.arange(ni2)

key = data[:,IDX1] * ni2 + data[:,IDX2] # 1D key to the rows

sortids = np.argsort(key) #indices to the sorted key
```

Then inside the loop instead of

```
mask=np.nonzero(...)
```

you need to do

```
curid = i1 * ni2 + i2
left = np.searchsorted(key, curid, 'left', sorter=sortids)
right=np.searchsorted(key, curid, 'right', sorter=sortids)
mask = sortids[left:right]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to compare numpy array of different sizes without using for loops. Would be hard to decide what is the output meaning and shape of something like

```
[0,1,2,3,4] == [3,4,2]
```

The only suggestion that I can give you is to get rid of one of the for loop using `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools as it

[...]

idx1s = np.unique(data[:,IDX1])
idx2s = np.unique(data[:,IDX2])

# initialize global sum variable to 0
cost = 0
for i1, i2 in it.product(idx1s, idx2):

    # for each block in the dataset
    mask = np.nonzero((data[:,IDX1] == i1) & (data[:,IDX2] == i2))

    # get variables for that block
    curr_X = X[mask,:]
    curr_y = y[mask]
    [...]
```

You can also keep `mask` as a bool array

```
mask = (data[:,IDX1] == i1) & (data[:,IDX2] == i2)
```

The output is the same and you have to use anyway the memory to create the bool array. Doing this way saves you some memory and a function evaluation

**EDIT**

If you know that the indices do not have holes or have few holes, might be worth to remove the part where you define `idx1s` and `idxs2` and change the for loop to

```
max1, max2 = data[:,[IDX1, IDX2]].max(axis=0)
for i1, i2 in it.product(xrange(max1), xrange(max2)):
    [...]
```

Both `xrange` and `it.product` are iterators, so they create only `i1` and `i2` when you need.

ps: if you are on python3.x use `range` instead of `xrange`

Comment: I was in doubt, so I just timed it: there is no relevant difference performance wise between having two smaller nested for loops, or a larger one over their Cartesian product. It does look cleaner, which is a good thing, but equally fast (or slow).

Comment: @Jaime thank for the test. I'll keep in mind. (For some reason I like itertools :D)